# JSF commandlink , onclick action not working?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i have many command links within an accordian panel . one such link calls the dialog during the onclick event . Below is the xhtml snippet .

```
<p:accordionPanel id="accordion" activeIndex="#{activeIndex.store}">
 <p:tab>
  <p:commandLink value="LRU Status Summary"
                        action="LRUStatusSummary.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
                        style="#{menuBean.getMenuItemCss('LRUStatus')}" onclick="PF('progress').show()"
                        actionListener="#{menuBean.initiate('LRUStatus')}">
                    </p:commandLink>
</p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>

<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="progress"
     closable="false" showHeader="false" resizable="false">
    <center>
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajax-loader-transparent.gif" />
    </center>
</p:dialog>
```

But the problem is , it gets called sometimes and sometimes it is not . i followed every step as said in this thread ([commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183)) . any help please ?

But if i remove the onclick event , it works fine . But if it is present , the action is not invoked at all sometimes(in all the browsers) . It misbehaves .( using IE v-10 , firefox v-30 , chrome v-31) .

The LRUStatus page takes about 30 secs to fetch the data from DB and to populate the fields in this xhtml . So i just thought of freezing the screen for those seconds (using "modal" attribute in dialog)

Comment: You're doing redirec on click ...what you want to do?

Comment: @Makky , question updated

Comment: actually it is working , only sometimes it is not working !! why i can't do ? any specific reason ?

Comment: What happens if you replace h:commandLink with p:commandLink ?

Comment: @Periklis !! i am getting the same output !! it is not redirected !!

Comment: In the code, that you have p:commandLink can you replace onclick with onstart and tell me if anything changes. Thanks

Comment: ya changed to onstart also !!! same output !! the URl changes like this "172.19.134.2:8084/maintenance2/faces/layout.xhtml#"; when i clcik on lrustatussummary ; a hash is getting appended

Comment: try adding ajax="false" on your p:commandLink

Comment: how will the onclick or onstart work ? if i give ajax = false ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, ignore my previous comment. Sorry, i dont have any idea what it might go wrong sometimes with your code. What you have written originally seems correct since the javascipt on the onclick will fire and then the action will be fired.